# WM_MOUSEMOVE LParam low-order Overflow

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

When i receive a [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message in WndProc the lParam contains the cursor coordinates. I translate this parameter into a `Point` structure:

```
Friend Shared Function LParamToPoint(ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Point
    Return New Point(LOWORD(lParam.ToInt32()), HIWORD(lParam.ToInt32()))
End Function

Friend Shared Function HIWORD(ByVal value As Integer) As Short
    Return CShort((value >> 16))
End Function

Friend Shared Function LOWORD(ByVal value As Integer) As Short
    Return CShort((value And UShort.MaxValue))
End Function
```

My problem is that when the x-coordinate of the cursor becomes negative the LOWORD function fails with an overflow exception. According to MSDN you should use the [GET_X_LPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GET_Y_LPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macros not the HI/LO WORD macros. But no such functions are available in vb.net.

So what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow checking really gets in the way here.  The best way to tackle this problem is by declaring a **union**.  A union is a structure that has overlapping values.  Which elegantly allows you to overlay an IntPtr on top of structure members that have type Short.  The conversion is *extremely* fast and cannot throw an overflow exception.

Add a new Module to your project, name it NativeMethods and make it look like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing

Module NativeMethods
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
    Public Structure LParamMap
        Public Sub New(value As IntPtr)
            lparam = value
        End Sub

        Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As LParamMap) As Point
            Return New Point(value.loword, value.hiword)
        End Operator

        <FieldOffset(0)> Public lparam As IntPtr
        <FieldOffset(0)> Public loword As Short
        <FieldOffset(2)> Public hiword As Short
    End Structure

End Module
```

I threw in a conversion operator for Point since that's the one you really want.  Some test code that exercises this:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Debug.Assert(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Dim test As New LParamMap(New IntPtr(-1))
        Debug.Assert(test.loword = -1)
        Debug.Assert(test.hiword = -1)
        Dim pos As Point = test
        Debug.Assert(pos = New Point(-1, -1))
    End Sub
 End Module
```

It now becomes a very simple one-liner in, say, an override of a form's WndProc() method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = &H200 Then
        Dim pos As Point = New LParamMap(m.LParam)
        '' etc...
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: This was way more elegant than my approach. Many thanks!